# How do I Find out words within a line using grep in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

Suppose, I have a string "Transferred 6.7828 MB in 244.434 seconds (28.4151 KB/sec)". I want to get 244.434 seconds out of this and this is just an example, these values can change. Basically I need to know the time taken (in seconds from this string). I am implementing this in Linux. How to do via grep?

This input will come from a log file abc.log.

Comment: With awk: `awk '{print $5}' <<< 'Transferred 6.7828 MB in 244.434 seconds (28.4151 KB/sec)'`

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this `grep`:

```
$ grep -oE "[0-9\.]* seconds" file
244.434 seconds
```

where `file`:

```
Transferred 6.7828 MB in 244.434 seconds (28.4151 KB/sec)
```

**EDIT**
(suggested by @Cyrus)

Assuming that you just want the amount of seconds:

```
$ grep -oP "[0-9.]+(?= seconds)" file
244.434
```

Comment: I suggest with GNU grep: `grep -oP "[0-9.]+(?= seconds)"`

Answer (score 2):

If you can be sure about the order of your output, then

```
echo "Transferred 6.7828 MB in 244.434 seconds (28.4151 KB/sec)" | cut -d' ' -f5
```

Output

```
244.434
```

At least is easier than sed.

Comment: Good thinking. `grep` may still be required to eliminate other lines from the log file.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think in that possibility, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need grep and sed for this:

```
grep "Transferred .* in .* seconds" abc.log | sed -e 's/^.*Transferred .* in \([0-9][0-9]*[.][0-9][0-9]*\) seconds .*/\1/'
```

Output:

```
244.434
```

Comment: Your capture group could be anything, better `sed 's/^.*in[ ]\([0-9][0-9]*[.][0-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/'` (but I like your fuller use of `"Transferred..."`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Good point.  Updated.

Comment: After you added the initial `grep`, then it would have probably been good enough either way (depending on what else could be in the log), but when needing to match numbers, it's always good to be explicit.

Comment: Realistically there should be no need for `sed` as `grep` has the `-o` option to output only the matching pattern.

Comment: @trs, there should similarly be no need for `grep` as `sed` can do the same search with a regex in `1addr`. There's no "one right way" to do most things.

Comment: @ghoti ... Well let's just rephrase it to "there is no need to pipe output to two programs". The point which you missed is that this answer suggests using both which is not necessary.

Comment: @trs, didn't miss it at all, that's exactly what I was saying. Perhaps you missed the fact that I was suggesting that *either* tool would work.